# CSS proper style linking in html

Tags: html, css

## I have the following file structure in my project:

- app

  - html

    - index.html
  - css

    - style.css

## the issue is that linking my style.css by the following wont work:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>`

because it is taking the path relative, so it thinks that the file is in
`app/html/css/style.css`

## and even if I give it the absolute path:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app/css/style.css"/>`

it just doesn't load the `style.css`

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: `href="../css/style.css"`.This tells the system to first go up one folder (parent) before going down into the css folder.

Comment: @Roel Strolenberg, ty that fixed the issue. If you answer properly I can give u sum up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telling the system to look for `href="css/style.css"` points it to the (non-existing) folder: `html/css/style.css` as your working directory (from which you are trying to reference the stylesheet) is the 'html' folder.

To fix this, you need to **first** go to its parent directory by prepending `../`. This points to the 'app' folder. From there you can go into the 'css' folder, resulting in:

`href="../css/style.css"`

Comment: this fixed my issue, thx for explanation